# how do I get iphone public key access?

Tags: iphone, authentication, signing

So, my company has an iPhone app.  We are publishing the API to our server, and we need to authenticate the client app (not the user, we want to know if this is the iPhone app that it claims to be).

What I'd like to be able to do is have the application send our server the public key for the application in the Apple app store as part of its initial request.  I'd then like our server to be able to ask the Apple store "is this public key the key for the application I think it is?"  If it is, then we would issue a valid token for all other requests, if not-- bounce the request.

I realize this approach can be spoofed (in that someone can just find the public key from a Jailbroken phone and pretend to be the app), but for the initial releases of the app, we don't care because we WANT people to use the app.  Later, we want to give attribution on API requests from partners (who are authorized to send requests using the method described above), but for now there is no need to sign or genuinely authorize the requests (with 2 or 3 legged oAuth).

So, simply put-- 
o  Is there a way for an iPhone app to ask iOS for the public key used to sign the app? 
o  Is there a way for a server or other program to ask the Apple store "is this public key the key for the app that I think it is?"

I'm essentially trying to use the Apple store as an authentication authority.  I know:  they are already in that they have to be signed and approved by Apple, but I need a server request-time validation.

Thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just create your own key and store it inside your app?  Then pass that key along with all requests to the API.

You can use this approach in conjunction with passing the version of the app.  This approach would allow you to restrict access to the API if an app key was no longer supported or allow you to block an outdated version of the app.

Comment: The problem is that, acting as my own certificate authority is just the same as accepting EVERY app.  I really need a third party to authenticate the app as what it claims to be.  The potential partners that will write apps for us are not necessarily skilled enough to write a server we could authenticate against.  For instance, the scenario of the app getting a token from their own server and passing it to our server which could validate it by calling their server before we issue our own is not possible.